# What conditions and requirements are needed to film sex scenes safely?

Tags: film-techniques, realism, effects

I have seen numerous movies with sex scenes:

**Friends with Benefits** is one, **No Strings attached** (insertion is not filmed here) and several others where the intercourse is actually on camera (the insertion as well).

This makes me curious as to what sort of conditions and requirements there are for both man and woman as to not cause accidental pregnancy, or transmit any STD, or any internal injuries.

**What do film producers do to ensure none of this happens and full safety is applied to the scene itself as well as the actors?**

Comment: Are you limiting this question to "proper" pornographic films?  Hollywood films of course don't include real sexual activity between actors.  Male actors (if naked) will wear 'socks' on the part of their anatomy that rhymes with 'sock'.

Comment: Related questions: [Do they really have sex in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/do-they-really-have-sex-in-movies) and [Do the actors really go nude in the shooting of the movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8864/do-the-actors-really-go-nude-in-the-shooting-of-the-movies/)

Comment: @Paulie_D But few films like Antichrist achieve to show proper sex somehow and I heard few film do real sex too while doubles doing the main part.

Comment: @Paulie_D - some (very rare) non-porn films do. Less uncommon with European ones, but still very, very occasional. Certainly a major studio release doesn't go there, but....  The independent film, Brown Bunny, got some infamy for the extremely explicit scene with Chloë Sevigny (mainstream actress, was in HBO series Big Love), for instance.

Comment: This wasn't really meant to be pornographic.

Comment: Just close the question already, I don't like how I worded it.

Comment: Plenty of independent or non-US films that can't be considered pornography have non-simulated sex scenes. I'm surprised film scholars Pete and Paulie_D do not know this.

Comment: Like I said...close it.

Comment: Not sure why the down-votes on this one - it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Paulie_D there are [non-porn films with unsimulated sexual activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsimulated_sex#Films_with_unsimulated_sexual_activity)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're not having sex (unless you're watching proper hard-core pornographic films).

A lot is implied, but it's only acting and you'll never visually the actual act happening.  If a male actor is nude, then they'll invariably be wearing a 'sock' for modesty.  Female actors may be naked, or wearing a [merkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkin).

Of course, most of what you see is stuff you don't see - acting is usually under covers, from behind, or off-camera (there being a close up of kissing/sweating instead of the 'lower' regions).

EDIT:  I'm referring here to mainstream Hollywood films as per the ones given in the question.  Obviously independent films or films creating in countries without Hollywood levels of obscenity laws can be as shocking/explicit as they like.

Comment: It will be useful to add that a lot of the time CGI is employed, like in [this Jessica Alba nude scene](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/wXWELpAnzMHoJ9QyPYIU7JCF2GQ=/400x0/filters:no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/3943630/NUDES-JESSICA_ALBA_610.0.jpg), to remove skin-coloured underwear. In Game of Thrones they tend to use body-doubles for nude scenes, and they replace the face in post with CGI, or otherwise cleverly shoot the scene to get around this.

Comment: True, there's a wide range of methods that allow actors not to have sex.  I'd guess that many viewers would find overly graphic sex (even if it's CGI generated) as somewhat distasteful/uncomfortable.

Comment: There are non-pornographic movies which feature non-simulated sex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsimulated_sex . And GoT doesn't use body doubles that often.

Comment: @BCdotWEB There's always going to be exceptions if you look hard enough.  I was answering this question in the view of fairly mainstream films as per the examples in the question).

Comment: Simply not true.  While rare, some non-porno films do show actual explicit sex or sex acts.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Would you care to look at the examples in the question - It's those mainstream films I was a dressing in my answer. You are more than free to supply your own answer as an alternative to mine.

Comment: "They're not having sex (unless you're watching proper hard-core pornographic films)." - is simply a false statement.  I don't need to supply a separate answer to point that out. The OP, while citing examples of films he/she has seen, never says that it is restricted to popular, mainstream distribution films.

Comment: "always going to be exceptions" is not the same as "NEVER."  Your answer is, thus, incorrect.

Comment: Un-downvoted due to the edit and added specificity.

Comment: Ditto, un-downvoted.